# Handling Window.close in JavaScript through UIWebView - Obj C

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I recently started working on a IOS project that runs mainly on a `UIWebView`.  Now my `UIWebView`is a delegate of `UIWebViewDelegate` and what I have encountered is that my app does not respond to `window.close` and other `window` events that `JavaScript` might call.  Now I am able to pick up a new `HTTP` request shot off through a `href` in my `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` delegate method.

My hope is to know if there is a way to listen for `window` events such as `window.close` in my `IOS` app and to retrieve the targets.  I want to stray away from `injecting` any sort of `JavaScript` into the page directly as much as possible!

Anyone care to explain if or if not this is possible and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `UIWebView` there is no way of achieving this without injecting some JavaScript. Even the newer `WKWebView` would still need JavaScript injection to make this work.

You would inject JavaScript that would override the `window.close` function and trigger a location change with something like `location.href = "uniquescheme://window.close";` which, as you say, could be handled in `shouldStartLoadWithRequest`.

Something like:

```
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.close = function () { location.href = 'uniquescheme://window.close'; }"]
```

Answer (score 4):

For `WKWebView` there are methods which catch the calls for (implement WKUIDelegate)

`window.open` : `createWebViewWithConfiguration: forNavigationAction: windowFeatures:`

and for

`window.close` : `webViewDidClose:(WKWebView *)webView NS_AVAILABLE(10_11, 9_0)`

mind it, it's only available 9.0 and up.

but not in `UIWebView`(actually still investigating if it can be done without injection, will update the answer if I find any)