# how to close popup in wkwebview (xamarin c#)

Tags: ios, xamarin, wkwebview, popupwindow

i created new popup in wkwebview (onclick="popopen(this.href))

```
 public override WKWebView CreateWebView(WKWebView webView, WKWebViewConfiguration configuration, WKNavigationAction navigationAction, WKWindowFeatures windowFeatures)
        {if (navigationAction.TargetFrame == null)
            {WKPreferences wkPreferences = new WKPreferences() { JavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true, JavaScriptEnabled = true };
                wkPreferences.SetValueForKey(NSObject.FromObject(true), (NSString)"allowFileAccessFromFileURLs");
                WKWebViewConfiguration wkConfig = new WKWebViewConfiguration();
                wkConfig.Preferences = wkPreferences;
                WKWebView webView1 = new WKWebView(new CGRect(0, 0, webView.Frame.Width, webView.Frame.Height), wkConfig);

                webView1.LoadRequest(navigationAction.Request);
                webView1.NavigationDelegate = new AllowAllDelegate();
                webView1.UIDelegate = this;
                webView1.Configuration.ProcessPool = webView.Configuration.ProcessPool;
            
                webView.Superview.AddSubview(webView1);}
```

and how to close new popup? (action like a href="#" onclick="..." )

Answer (score 0):

Make `webView1` as global variable and then remove it in `DidClose` method .

```
public override void DidClose(WKWebView webView)
{
     webView1.RemoveFromSuperview();
     webView1 = null;
}
```

Comment: thx for the your help i made your code but didn't call DisClose method
  [Foundation.Export("webViewDidClose:")]
            public override void DidClose(WKWebView webView)
            {      
            }    
how to detect DidClose method?

Comment: Execute the js code from webview ,  check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31842899/handling-window-close-in-javascript-through-uiwebview-obj-c， maybe helpful